# iOS URL link in email not showing "Open in" option

Tags: ios, url, types, document

My iOS application has registered for an URL document type. A 3rd party app has also registered for the same URL. When I click on the URL link in mail, I don't get the "Open in" option. Instead, the app that was installed first gets launched. How do I get the mail to show the "Open in" option.